# Ansible with Git module

Tags: git, ansible

I have the following playbook which I am trying to build to simply pull down the latest version of the file in bitbacket

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  remote_user: r_ansible
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  any_errors_fatal: True
  vars_files:
    - /home/r_ansible/playbooks/group_vars/git_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - git:
        repo: "https://{{ git_repo.usr }}:{{ git_repo.pwd|urlencode() }}@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git"
        dest: /home/r_ansible/playbooks/
        remote: origin
```

I get the following error:

```
TASK [git] *************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git reset --hard origin", "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to checkout branch master", "rc": 128, "stderr": "fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.\nUse '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:\n'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'\n", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.", "Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:", "'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/r_ansible/playbooks/pb_local_update_code.retry
```

I guess I am just not sure what is meant by:`"fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Current git status

```
 git show-branch -a
* [master] working
 ! [origin/master] working
--
*+ [master] working

$git branch
* master
$git branch -r
  origin/master
$git pull origin
  Already up-to-date.
```

Thanks
alexis

Comment: this is more of a git issue, rather an ansible issue, can you try cloning to a different directory ?

Comment: @deepak I am not sure how I would pull down just a directory? I am trying to pull down the entire repo.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to resolve this. I am not sure what the issue was but completely deleting the local repo and cloning it again resolved the issue

thanks
alexis

Comment: Looks quite related to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/22502 I fixed for ansible. I think there was another instance where this need to fixed . Can you file a bug in ansible and tag me ? I am Miyurz on github. Also, Can you let me know what ansible version you are using ?